# How to drag elements with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How can we drag and place objects on an web page using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

I see that you don't use jQquery tag, but if you can use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) life can be more simple.

Answer (score 1):

Its so easy with with jQuery UI:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my_draggable_elems').draggable();
});
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I can suggest **REDIPS.drag** JavaScript library. Minimized and GZIPped it's less then 10Kb but offers a lot of functionality. Library uses HTML table as layout. DIV elements in table cell can be dragged to other table cells. With writting JavaScript code in event handlers, almost any scenario can be covered.

Here is a link to demo page. Near to download button is "Preview" link where you can find content of whole package.

http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/